# Error creating bean with the name 'transactionmanager' with spring roo

Tags: spring, spring-roo

This is a the script I use to create my spring roo app :

```
// Spring Roo 1.1.5.RELEASE [rev d3a68c3] log opened at 2011-11-21 11:16:11
project --topLevelPackage school.javafinal
persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY
entity --class ~.model.Brand
field string --fieldName name --sizeMax 70
entity --class ~.model.Category
field string --fieldName name --sizeMax 70
entity --class ~.model.Comment
field string --fieldName content --sizeMax 2000
field date --fieldName created_on --type java.util.Date
entity --class ~.model.Orders
field date --fieldName created_on --type java.util.Date
field number --fieldName price --type java.lang.Float
entity --class ~.model.OrderDetails
field date --fieldName created_on --type java.util.Date
entity --class ~.model.OrderStatuses
enum type --class ~.model.EOrderStatus
enum constant --name Pending
enum constant --name Denied
enum constant --name Complete
field enum --fieldName status --type ~.model.EOrderStatus
entity --class ~.model.Product
field date --fieldName created_on --type java.util.Date
field string --fieldName name --sizeMax 100
field string --fieldName imageUrl --sizeMax 1000
field string --fieldName specs --sizeMax 4000
field string --fieldName description --sizeMax 4000
field string --fieldName warranty --sizeMax 100
field number --fieldName price --type java.lang.Float
field number --fieldName quantity --type java.lang.Short
field number --fieldName rate --type java.lang.Float --decimalMax 5
// Reference
focus --class ~.model.Product
field set --fieldName comments --type ~.model.Comment --cardinality ONE_TO_MANY --mappedBy product
focus --class ~.model.Orders
field reference --class ~.model.Orders --fieldName status --type ~.model.OrderStatuses
field reference --class ~.model.Product --fieldName status --type ~.model.Brand
```

When I run the app with mvn jetty:run , I have the error in context initialization :

> Error creating bean with the name 'transactinmanager'

How can I fix this, thanks so much for reading my question :)

Comment: Should `transactinmanager` actually be `transactionmanager`? I can't find reference to either spelling in your config but I've been stumped a few times by a simple typo before.

Comment: yes, it is. I fixed the title

Comment: What I meant was, is the typo in your code?

Comment: no, I resolved the problem myself. I will post the answer below.
@Russell: Thanks for your help along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the tutorial in Spring CookBook and it looks like

> --mappedBy

does not appear in the latest spring-roo